# Looking for a string in a list of items with Python works locally but not on EC2

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Python script that works fine on my local machine:

```
fileC = open(locationA + filenameC, 'r')

listActivities = 'listActivities.log'
outputfile = open(locationA + listActivities, 'w')  
fileA = open(location + filenameA, 'r')
fileA = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fileA]   
Alines =  set(fileA) 

for item in Alines:
        outputfile.write("%s\n" % item)

for lineC in fileC:

    fieldC = lineC.split('#')
    fieldComp = fieldC[0]+'#'+fieldC[2] 
    outputfile.write("fieldComp: %s \n" % fieldComp)
    p = 0
    if fieldComp in Alines:
        p = utils.clicksAfterConversion(fieldC[0], fieldC[2], fieldC[1])
```

My goal is to find the fieldComp in the list Alines and do further processing. The problem is that it works locally, but once on AWS it doesn't find any correspondance for FieldComp in Alines.
I have noticed that when I right in a seperate file all the items of Alines (outputfile.write("%s\n" % item))  , some spaces are added at the end of each row on AWS whereas it isn't the case locally. I suspect it comes from this, but I don't have any other idea ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will fix the problem or not but, you said each line has some spaces added to it in AWS. A regular expression match might fit your case.

instead of using

```
if fieldComp in Alines:
```

you could use regexes. for instance,

```
import re
...
blah blah code here
...
...
for item in Alines:
    if re.search(fieldComp, item):
        p = utils.clicksAfterConversion(fieldC[0], fieldC[2], fieldC[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Tag Groff. The problem with your solution is that I cannot apply it for my case, as FileC is massive (millions of rows) and the are few thousnads of items. Adding a new For loop makes the script too slow..

Answer (score 1):

ok in that case regular expresions probably aren't the answer. After doing some searching I found the fnmatch module. it allows searching using shell like wildcards. It also supports list filtering, so you might be able to get away with this.

```
import fnmatch
...
if fnmatch.filter(Alines, "%s*" % fieldComp):
    p = utils.clicksAfterConversion(fieldC[0], fieldC[2], fieldC[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but still too slow compared to a simple search in a list. I think I give up on this one, and I just realized I could use Hive and managed to do what I want with a simple join and filter. Thanks for your help.